# Using scope with TTL in Couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase

I have a couple of questions in couchbase 7 version :

1. What will a TTL set on scope do ? I assume it will delete the data and collections within it because its not clearly described.
2. What will a TTL set on collection do ? I know it will delete the collection but seems we will also have to delete the K,V first which is the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a TTL on a scope ([see documentation here](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/data/expiration.html)): "TTL can be established on collections: it cannot be established on scopes."

As for TTL on a collection, expiration will NOT delete the collection. Setting a TTL on a collection specifies the TTL for *all documents* in the collection.

You can also set TTL on individual documents (using the KV API).